# Pivot rows to columns based on content in Oracle 10g PL/SQL

Tags: plsql, oracle10g, pivot

I have a table in my database, `user_answers` that stores users answers to a series of questions, with rows; `user_id`, `question_id`, `answer_id` and `text_entry`.  Question text and answer text (if any) are stored in lookup tables.  There are three types of questions, single-answer questions, multiple-answer questions and text-entry answer questions.  So a single user might have entries like the following in the `user_answers` table:

```
user_id    question_id    answer_id    text_entry
-------    -----------    ---------    ----------
  123          100          1010         (null)
  123          200          2010         (null)
  123          200          2030         (null)
  123          300          3000       "code 789"
```

Lets say the `questions_text` table has:

```
question_id         text
-----------    -------------
    100           "Gender"
    200         "Interests"
    300         "Your code"
```

and the `answers_text` table has:

```
answer_id       text
---------    -----------
   1010       "Female"
   1020        "Male"
   2010       "Sports"
   2020      "Computers"
   2030       "Movies"
   3000        (null)
```

I want to extract the data into a csv with one line per user_id showing the answers, something like this:

```
User,Gender,Sports,Computers,Movies,Code
123,Female,1,0,1,code 789
```

I know how to generate the CSV file via SQLPlus (I only have access to the DB via SQLPlus for reasons beyond my control...) but I don't know how to generate the PL/SQL statement.

In PL/SQL I know I can generate a pivot of the Gender question by doing

```
SELECT
   user_id || ',' ||
   MIN(DECODE(question_id, '100', (SELECT text FROM answers_text where answer_id = answer_text.answer_id)))
FROM user_answers
GROUP BY user_id
ORDER BY user_id
;
```

(I'm not an SQL guy, so this is copied off the internets!)

This code is (at least as far as my testing is telling me) good for the single-answer questions but will not work on multiple-answer or text-entry type questions.

I saw some stuff online about using the `case` statement in PL/SQL like so:

```
MIN(CASE WHEN question_id = '200' AND answer_id = '2010' THEN '1' ELSE '0' END)
```

...but I can't figure out how to get the answers into columns. And all the SO questions I can find that might be related are sql-server specific.

Is there a way to generate my desired output from a single PL/SQL statement?  Preferably written in a way that does not depend on the data in the tables as we have a number of databases that this might need to be run on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To accomplish what you are looking for (and not be specific to this data) I believe you are going to need some extra fields in your tables.  For example, you will need to know which questions are Single-Answer, Multi-Answer, and Text-Entry without having to look at the data.  You will also need to know which answers are possible for your Multi-answer questions without having to link through the data.  From there, you can loop through the meta information about each question / answer combination and build yourself a query to run that will return the data in your desired format.  Something like:

```
/* Create Tables with Data - Note 2 new columns added to questions_text */
create table user_answers
as
 select 123 user_id, 100 question_id, 1010 answer_id, null text_entry from dual
 union all
 select 123 user_id, 200 question_id, 2010 answer_id, null text_entry from dual
 union all
 select 123 user_id, 200 question_id, 2030 answer_id, null text_entry from dual
 union all
 select 123 user_id, 300 question_id, 3000 answer_id, 'code 789' text_entry from dual;

create table questions_text
as
 select 100 question_id, 'Gender' question_text, 'S' question_type, 1000 answer_set_id from dual
 union all
 select 200 question_id, 'Interests' question_text, 'M' question_type, 2000 answer_set_id from dual
 union all
 select 300 question_id, 'Your code' question_text, 'T' question_type, 3000 answer_set_id from dual;

create table answers_text
as
 select 1010 answer_id, 'Female' text, 1000 answer_set_id from dual
 union all
 select 1020 answer_id, 'Male' text, 1000 answer_set_id from dual
 union all
 select 2010 answer_id, 'Sports' text, 2000 answer_set_id from dual
 union all
 select 2020 answer_id, 'Computers' text, 2000 answer_set_id from dual
 union all
 select 2030 answer_id, 'Movies' text, 2000 answer_set_id from dual
 union all
 select 3000 answer_id, null text, 3000 answer_set_id from dual;


/* PL/SQL for creating SQL statement to return data in desired format */
declare
 v_sql VARCHAR2(32767);
begin
 v_sql := 'select ua.user_id "User",';
 FOR question IN (
  select question_id, question_text, question_type, answer_set_id
  from questions_text
 )
 LOOP
  IF question.question_type = 'M'
  THEN
   FOR answer IN (
    select answer_id, text
    from answers_text
    where answer_set_id = question.answer_set_id
   )
   LOOP
    v_sql := v_sql||chr(10)||'max(case when ua.question_id = '||question.question_id||' and ua.answer_id = '||answer.answer_id||' then 1 else 0 end) "'||answer.text||'",';
   END LOOP;
  ELSIF question.question_type = 'S'
  THEN
   v_sql := v_sql||chr(10)||'min(case when ua.question_id = '||question.question_id||' then at.text end) "'||question.question_text||'",';
  ELSIF question.question_type = 'T'
  THEN
   v_sql := v_sql||chr(10)||'min(case when ua.question_id = '||question.question_id||' then ua.text_entry end) "'||question.question_text||'",';
  END IF;
 END LOOP;
 v_sql := rtrim(v_sql,',');
 v_sql := v_sql||' from
 user_answers ua
 inner join questions_text qt
  on qt.question_id = ua.question_id
 inner join answers_text at
  on at.answer_id = ua.answer_id
 group by
  ua.user_id';
 -- replace dbms_output with code to write file
 dbms_output.put_line(v_sql);
END;
```

Comment: Thanks cmartin2.  I ended up using something more dependent on the specific code for this case.  Long term I plan to use something based on your answer -- the additional information you have is in the questions table or can be constructed (in the case of the answer_id_set which is the question_id + 10x0 where x increments for each question, i.e. 1010, 1020 etc.)

Answer (score 1):

Queries with an unknown number of columns are problematic at best. Will you really not know what the data will look like? You might want to look at this [Ask Tom](http://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:766825833740#14642820392307) response for a package which might help get you the results you need.